# Github network graph looks like metro map

Tags: git, github

I was just wondering if other people working in a team using github for private projects had the same kind of Network map ?

[alt text http://a.yfrog.com/img715/1711/95n.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img715/1711/95n.png)

Or are we doing something obviously wrong ?

Comment: I love the metro map description, had the same thoughts myself

Comment: How did you created that long view of the Network Graph?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for other people's opinions, not a specific programming problem.

Comment: Somebody has just implemented Paris metro map with it :) https://github.com/vbarbaresi/MetroGit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I kind of had the same concern with my team's network map looking something like yours and wasn't sure how all the local branches showed up there. I got a nice and detailed answer to my question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959157/local-branches-show-up-on-githubs-network-view/2964148#2964148) as to where all that clutter appears to be coming from. Other than that you don't need to worry too much about how the map looks, you've got to stick to a workflow that works for your team and don't be afraid of experimenting.

Comment: Basically you're right, but the lines like the long, bottom, magenta line show that one branch was in development for a very longer time, rarely being re-merged/based with any trunk - which can lead to complex & sometimes time-consuming conflict resolution.

Answer (score 5):

No, it just seems [GitHub's network graph stinks (archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215062809/http://subimage.com/blog/2011/08/30/github-your-network-graph-sucks).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if your network graph is common amongst other GitHub projects, but it has only only one issue:

**The main reference line (top block one) is not linear.**
Meaning anyone pulling from it some time ago is likely, when he/she finally update its local copy, to apply the "[RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase)" paragraph if they want to apply their local work on top of the new history.

Other than that, long-lived branches (like the bottom red one) are always harder to merge (but off course, much easier than with Subversion).
Nothing major though.